# Обработка исключений в потоках

Tags: c++, многопоточность, исключения

Помогите пожалуйста выйти из творческого тупика:

main вызывает `std::thread1.detach()`... thread1 вызывает `thread2.detach()`, а thread2 вызывает `thread3.detach()`.

**Как вывести причины краша в thread3?** (причина именно в этом потоке (так как до этого всё работало, а менялся только он), но простой вызов try/catch ничего не даёт)

Comment: @Abyx, Отладка возможна только исполняемого файла. Приложение не работает без параметров инициализации, которые может дать только установщик. Вручную нереально много инициализировать. Тем более, краш не систематический, а происходит рандомно примерно после 20-40 секунд работы и выполнения данного потока.

Comment: @Abyx, крешдамп ругается на `memcpy`. "нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу" при использовании `memcpy`. Как такое может быть - то оно работает, то нет, рандомно?

Comment: Посмотрите по коду в каких случаях меняется указатель (первый аргумент `memcpy`). От этих мест и ищите ошибку. Т.е. при определенных условиях в него заносится неправильный адрес, либо он указывает на память в куче  (достаточно большой кусок), которая уже освобождена. Кстати, напишите, какая ОС?

Comment: @avp, ОС - Win 10 Enterprise x64. Порядок действий функции, вызываемой потоком, простой: создаём буфер `unsigned char * frame_buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(WebCam->GetFrameSize());`, лочим получение кадра с камеры, которое выполняется непрерывно в параллельном потоке, `M_Camera.lock();`, копируем содержимое кадра в буфер и снимаем лок `memcpy(frame_buffer, WebCam->GetFrameData(), WebCam->GetFrameSize()); M_Camera.unlock();`... Дальше работаем с буфером и перед последней фигурной скобкой функции вызывается `free(frame_buffer);`. Памяти 16 Гб, утечек нет - чего оно выделывается???

Comment: Вы уверены, что `GetFrameSize` в `malloc()` всегда больше или равен `GetFrameSize` в `memcpy()`?

Comment: @avp, да - он фиксируется ещё в main при отработке конструктора экземпляра класса камеры и больше не меняется - только читается

Comment: @avp, я дико извиняюсь за потраченное Вами время на комментарии! Причина в другом потоке - в него передавался адрес переменной, срок жизни которой кончался раньше, чем завершался поток, изменяющий её. Прошу прощения

Comment: @Iceman, не за что. Отлично, что нашли ошибку. В самом деле, это хороший способ. Начинаешь кому-то рассказывать о ней, а потом, бац, и нашел (даже в другом месте).